# How can I create a generic DetailView with a form for creating related objects

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I want a DetailView for a blog post, with a form that can be used to create related comments.

I want the features of a CreateView dependent on the Comment model and DetailView dependent on the Blog model

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Django comments app? If so, use a detail view for the blog model and include the comments using the template tag.